# Parse string to JSON in FluentD

Tags: json, parsing, fluentd

I have this log string:

```
2019-03-18 15:56:57.5522 | HandFarm | ResolveDispatcher | start resolving msg: 8
```

Please tell me how I can parse this string to JSON format in fluentd.conf?  I need the following format:

```
{
  "timestamp"  : "2019-03-18 15:56:57.5522",
  "system"  : "HandFarm",
  "module": "ResolveDispatcher",
  "message": "start resolving msg: 8",
}
```

I tried to use standard formatters, nothing came of it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [regexp](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/regexp) parser and format events to JSON. Here is an example of mine where I am reading the input from log file tail(with same input as yours) and output to stdout. Let me know.

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /tailsource/t.log
  pos_file /tailpos/t.log.pos
  read_from_head true
  tag temp
  <parse>
    @type regexp
    expression /^(?<timestamp>.*?)\s\| (?<system>.*?)\s\| (?<module>.*?)\s\| (?<message>.*)$/
  </parse>
</source>

<match>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

Here is sample output -

> {"timestamp":"2019-03-18
> 15:56:57.5522","system":"HandFarm","module":"ResolveDispatcher","message":"start
> resolving msg: 8"}

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Where is the JSON config in here?

Comment: @shadfc I believe parser by default formats it into JSON. I am trying to find documentation which can support this but can't find it yet.

Comment: This link https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/regexp describes the regexp parser plugin

Comment: @MikaRiekkinen thanks mika. updated the answer with new link.